# Can SVM hyperplane always separate data?

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning

According to this post SVM problem is a convex problem with convex constraints. Now what I am really struggling to understand if SVM is a convex problem, can we draw separating hyperplane for every classification problem? Am I thinking it wrongly?

Comment: No, not all data is linearly separable...

Answer (score 1):

By convex optimization problem, it means the objective function is convex and the feasible set is convex.

It doesn't imply that every problem is linearly separable. It is possible for two distinct data having the same feature $x$, and they belong to different classes.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more? If the cost function is convex, how can it misclassify some samples and still find the minimal cost?

Comment: The situation could be very bad that no matter what we do, we make mistake, however, we can still try our best to minimize our mistake.